# How can you open a link in a new tab and go directly to the tab in one click?

Tags: firefox

Atomic Web Browser allows you to open a tab and make the current one go in the background. Does Firefox offer something like this? If not, do any plugins do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Tools > Options > Tabs` and check the option "When I open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately".

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This is just what I was looking for. Thank you!